# write the results of a R loop into a csv

Tags: r

This is a csv including details of many papers such as the title of the paper and authors' address of the paper. I'm trying to extract names from the string about authors' address. 
One of the strings is as follows.

```
Jacod, Jean@Univ Paris 06, Inst Math Jussieu, F-75005 Paris, 
France::Reiss, Markus@Humboldt Univ, Inst Math, D-10099 Berlin, 
Germany
```

And my target is to print "Jacod, Jean" "Reiss, Markus" the 2 names in 2 cells of a row in a new csv.

```
Jacod, Jean   Reiss, Markus
```

I can extract the keyword from a long string. But I can't output all results of a R loop in only one csv.

I tried to use "write.csv" in the loop, but failed.

```
data<-read.csv('E:\\data\\ANNALS.csv')
da<-data$authors_address
for (string in da){
    re<-sub('(^.+)@.*$', '\\1', unlist(strsplit(string, '::')))
    write.csv(re,file="E:\\output.csv",append=TRUE)
}
```

I hope to output a new csv, in which every row contains the 2~3 authors'names of a paper. The result of codes above is the error "There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)"

Comment: why dont you save the results in a data.frame and then save that in a csv?

Comment: You describe this file as a CSV, which may technically be true, but it appears that a given paper spans 3 lines.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code and your description of the data I've deduced that each string in `data$authors_address` actually looks more like this, with author info separated by `::`:

```r
Jacod, Jean@Univ Paris 06, Inst Math Jussieu, F-75005 Paris, France::Reiss, Markus@Humboldt Univ, Inst Math, D-10099 Berlin, Germany
```

One suggestion: A CSV is simply one type of flat file, and it might not be appropriate for your output if the number of authors varies. It's still doable, but their are better options. A simple text file, where each group of authors is appended to a new line, would work quite well. For example:

```r
for (s in data$authors_address){
    re <- paste(sub("(.*)@.*", "\\1", strsplit(s, "::")[[1]]), collapse = " - ")
    write(re, "E:\\output.txt", append = T)
}
```

The file `output.txt` would look something like this:

```
Jacod, Jean - Reiss, Markus
Doe, John - Doe, Jane - Guy, Some
Butts, Seymour
...
```

Note that I first collapse the vectors using `-` as a separator, otherwise each vector element would be appended to its own line. You'll also need to to this if you use one of the other `write.*` options.

You could do something similar using `write.table` *(`write.csv` can be a little weird when appending, so I don't recommend it)*, but a few more arguments are needed to get it right:

```r
for (s in data$authors_address){
    re <- paste(sub("(.*)@.*", "\\1", strsplit(s, "::")[[1]]), collapse = " - ")
    write.table(re, file = "E:\\output.csv", append = T, sep = ",", col.names = F,
                row.names = F
                )
    }
```

As you can see, using `write` instead of `write.table`/`write.csv` simplifies things quite a bit.